# Where does macOS save apple id associated with an app?

Tags: applications, apple-id, mac-appstore

How can I find the apple id associated with an application that purchased from Mac App Store?

Earlier we could have find this information from `.plist` file that placed inside the app bundle. Now I am not able to find this piece of information there. Does macOS save **apple id - application** pair some where in any other form?

I am using macOS Sierra v10.12.2 (16C67).

Comment: MacOS assigns decryption keys to the apps you have purchased. It doesn't write the Apple ID in plaintext.

Comment: @bret7600 where can I find the key? Will it be different for each apps?